# How to create admin portal on google firebase for application on google firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using **GoolgeFirebase** for my android application. I want to make an admin portal at **GoogleFirebase** connected to that application's database to view some admin related tasks, like showing `waiters` with `rating` where i have all the `wiaters` and `rating` data stored in **Google Firebase Realtime Database**.

Do i have to create a web app, connected and hosted at the **Google Firebase** or the **GoogleFirebase** facilitate itslef for creating some admin portal for the android app.

Comment: You'll have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build *something*. A web app using firebase hosting is really easy but you can host it anywhere you want including on your own PC. Of course you can also build any kind of app using one of the SDKs or anything that can do HTTPS requests. An special admin android app is an option. Java desktop GUI app may be to your liking.

Sometimes I find building a commandline tool in node.js is perfect for my needs. The command line lets me pipe the output to other tools that are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides a number of [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to help build server-side or desktop applications. As of now there are Admin SDKs available for Node.js, Java and Python (although the Python SDK is new and doesn't have realtime DB support yet). You can use one of these SDKs to build your admin portal webapp.